# XML Variables don't allow inspection in IntelliJ 11 Flex Debugger

Tags: xml, apache-flex, intellij-idea, e4x

I recently upgraded to IntelliJ 11 and the version 10 debugger used to allow for E4X / XML debugging. I was able to expand the children and inspect elements/attributes of XML but now I can't get that to work. Has something changed/broken? Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image: Broken Debugger Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was a configuration error in my IntelliJ project. I had to make sure to have the SDK set properly.

I deleted the SDK I had set on this project and recreated it. Then I went into each module and set it to the correct SDK (not project sdk) and things started working.